# Load one line at a time

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering if there is a way to get jquery to load one line at a time.  I use

```
var old = $('#screen').html(),
    str = $.URLEncode(glength);

$('#screen').load('returns.php?c='+str+'',{},function(response, status, xhr){
    if (status == "error") {
      var msg = "FATAL ERROR: ";
      $("#screen").html("\n"+ xhr.status);
      $(this).prepend(old);
    } else {
        $(this).prepend(old);
        $('#command').focus();
    }
});
```

To load the data.  #screen is a pre.  And it's getting variables like this:

```
******************************************************************************
login [username] [email]          | Log in to the system
logout                            | Log out of the system
data                              | Display logged in user information
******************************************************************************
```

Is this possible, or am I dreaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `response` all your data with multiple lines?

You can use a `setTimeout`

```
var lines = response.split("\n");

var time = 0;
$(lines).each(function(i) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("<span />").html(this).prependTo("place");
    }, time);
    time += 200;
});
```

All lines will be appended, with about `200ms` delay between each.

Comment: Thanks.  With a little bit of tweaking, this turned out to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the lines you received from the server. Then use setTimeout to show them one after another. You can even show it character by character if you want. Check out the [Greplin challenge](http://challenge.greplin.com/) for an example. If you want the code I'll show you an example.

Comment: I'm creating a kind of command prompt emulator.  When a large block of data, like the one I added there is being shown, I want to emulate the older computers and load one line at a time, rather than all at once.

Comment: Yeah, that seems just about what I am going for.